# EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, node-modules, eslint

I deployed my react app to azure and on load, I got this error:
Failed to compile

EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache'

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

I have spent a couple of days trying to rectify it, all to no avail. Please, I need help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N7zJ.png)

Comment: Have you read the [deployment section](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)?

Comment: Why do you build on the production server? Deploy only the built project.

Comment: This is my first time deploying a react app. I followed a tutorial that describes how to deploy from my local machine to Azure App Service via git. How in particular am i to deploy just the built project?  https://css-tricks.com/deploying-a-client-side-rendered-create-react-app-to-microsoft-azure/

Answer (score 1):

if you have a typo in your code and saved it, then `.eslintcache` doesn't get cleared and the error will  appear in the server continuously . You have to delete `.eslintcache`. to overcome from this error.

**References** :

. [How to deploy React app to azure](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/deploy-a-react-app-to-azure)

.  [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10161) issue .

Answer (score 0):

You can chmod the file back to you. Actually in my case I had to change the ownership of the whole node_modules cache:

`chmod a+wr node_modules/.cache`

Answer (score -1):

The only way to overcome this issue is given below:

●Delete all files without (public and src).(if you delete public and src this will delete all your progress)
●Then create a new react app with [ $npx create-react-app ]
●exchange the public and src files with your project public and src
● npm start and hopefully it worked for you .